# Extend the built-in PHP GD fonts

Tags: php, image, fonts, gd

I like the built-in fonts for GD, they're small, fit tidily in the pixel grid, and come in a range of useful sizes.

But they only support the 32-255 character range.

Is it possible to extend these fonts in any way? For instance, I want to allow Japanese characters. Using fullwidth characters I'd want to produce something like this (from Wikipedia)

[image: characters]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/KoreanDOSPrompt.png))</sub>

Is there any way to extend the built-in font like this? Or alternatively, is there a font available that is the same as the built-in one but with support for more characters? Any TTF font I've tried to use results in antialiasing, which is disastrous on palette-based images...

Answer (score 0):

[According to the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), you can disable antialiasing for TTF fonts by using the negative of a color index for the `color` parameter of the `imagettftext` function.